# Routing is lost with mysite.com/about on Heroku/Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to access **mysite.com/about** I get routed to the www.mysite.com root, not to /about. I can only get to the /about page when I specify **www.mysite.com/about** directly.

How can I get routed to /about from mysite.com/about?

---

I am using a URL REDIRECT at namecheap to map mysite.com to www.mysite.com
and CNAME to map www.brandwink.com to mysite.herokuapp.com

route:

```
 match 'about', to: 'home#about', as: :about, via: :get
```

Comment: Post your routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you redirecting at the application level, or the DNS level (via a forward)?

You should be using the later, redirecting via forwarding your apex domain (`mysite.com`) to a subdomain (typically `www`), and then the subdomain should be a `CNAME` to your Heroku app.

- [Heroku DevCenter: Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: Yup, doing exactly that. Added the forwarding info to the question.

Comment: is URL REDIRECT the same thing as DNS forwarding?